# Node Mongo Patch request not syncronous using await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I'm having issues with syncing returns while using await.  All the info updates in mongo with no issue, the problem lies in that res.status(200).send(updatedData); returns the old data not the patched one.

```
const updateUserData = async (req, res) => {
if (!(req.params.id && req.body.id && req.params.id === req.body.id)) {
        const message =
          `Request path id (${req.params.id}) and request body id ` +
          `(${req.body.id}) must match`;
        console.error(message);
        return res.status(400).json({ message: message });
    }
try{
    const toUpdate = {};
    const updateableFields = ["username","firstName", "lastName","bio","settings","cardCollection", "avatar"];

    updateableFields.forEach(field => {
    if (field in req.body) {
      toUpdate[field] = req.body[field];
    }
    }); 
    const id = req.params.id;
    if(!id) return res.status(404).send({message:"id not found"})
    if(!toUpdate) return res.status(404).send({message:"text not found"})
    const updatedData = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, toUpdate);
    console.log(updatedData);
    res.status(200).send(updatedData);
}
catch(err){
  res.status(500).send({message:"unable to update data"})
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass the third parameter to [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) the options as `{new : true}` to return the updated document.